# Changing a Textbox to a Button in Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm working on a todo list program in google script. I have it so that people can type in their task in a textbox, but I want it so that once they hit the enter key, the textbox turns into a button that, that says what the task is, and they will later press when they finished that task and it will return to a textbox. I can't figure out how to make any changes to the app from inside another function.

What I have so far is:

```
function doGet(e) {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var panel = app.createAbsolutePanel().setHeight("750px").setWidth("1600px");
  var button = app.createButton("swag");
  var enterHandler = app.createServerKeyHandler('enterPress');
  enterHandler.addCallbackElement(panel);

  var box = app.createTextBox().addKeyUpHandler(enterHandler);

  panel.add(box,0,0);
  app.add(panel);
  return app;
}

function enterPress(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  if (e.parameter.keyCode==13){
    var button2 =app.createButton('swag');
    var panel = app.createAbsolutePanel().setHeight('750px').setWidth('1600px');
    panel.add(button2,0,0);
    app.add(panel);
  }
  return app;
}
```

It recognizes the enter press, but the changes won't return to the main app.

Comment: Have you looked into the HTMLService? It seems like it might be more capable of what you're trying to do, since you can use it to insert javascript into your UI.

Comment: No, I have not looked into it yet. but I will, thanks!

Comment: thanks for accepting ;-) I updated the code (and test) to get a better look & feel (imho) ;-)

Comment: Np! Thanks! But here's where I'm at now: I have it so they can hit the enter key instead of a confirm button, and it works fine, but now I have two text boxes and when I hit enter on one text box, it turns the other box into a button as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this :

note : I didn't "place" the button, I guess you have an idea on how you want them to show up...

You could also use a grid to place them... as you want.

```
function doGet(e) {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var panel = app.createAbsolutePanel().setHeight("750px").setWidth("1600px");
  var enterHandler = app.createServerKeyHandler('enterPress').addCallbackElement(panel);
  var button = app.createButton("confirm",enterHandler).setId('swag');
  var tBox = app.createTextBox().setName('tBox').setId('tBox').setWidth(300).setStyleAttributes({'textAlign':'center'});
  var bBox = app.createButton("no Text",enterHandler).setVisible(false).setId('bBox').setWidth(300);
  panel.add(tBox,20,20).add(bBox,20,20).add(button,140,50);
  app.add(panel);
  return app;
}

function enterPress(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  if (e.parameter.source=='bBox'){
    app.getElementById('bBox').setVisible(false);
    app.getElementById('tBox').setVisible(true);
  }
  if (e.parameter.source=='swag'){
    app.getElementById('bBox').setVisible(true).setHTML(e.parameter.tBox);
    app.getElementById('tBox').setVisible(false);
  }
  return app;
}
```

[Test here](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbw7aKeo2uKXlhhznpx6tooOMjsLIbUcppmM29V3S5GyhIay4Xs/exec)

**Edit:**  code modified with placement .

**EDIT2 :** You could also hide the enter button, I find it nicer.

```
function enterPress(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  if (e.parameter.source=='bBox'){
    app.getElementById('bBox').setVisible(false);
    app.getElementById('tBox').setVisible(true);
    app.getElementById('swag').setVisible(true);
  }
  if (e.parameter.source=='swag'){
    app.getElementById('bBox').setVisible(true).setHTML(e.parameter.tBox);
    app.getElementById('tBox').setVisible(false);
    app.getElementById('swag').setVisible(false);
  }
  return app;
}
```